# Convert to uppercase in shell

Tags: shell, awk, uppercase

I am reading a character from keyboard and converting it to uppercase and then displaying the character again.

But the following code produces an error:

```
read a;
a=echo $a | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
echo $a
```

I also tried this:

```
read option;
eval $(awk -v option=$option '{print "a="toupper(option);}')
echo $a
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to store the result of `a` back in `a`, then you can do use *command substitution*:

```
read a;
a=$(echo $a | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
echo $a
```

Comment: This works for some languages but not all. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455313/289099 for a more widely-applicable solution. Specifically, use `tr` like so: `tr [:lower:] [:upper:];`

Answer (score 31):

This can be done natively in Bash as follows:

```
read a;
a="${a^^}"
echo "$a"
```

There is no need to invoke other commands like `tr`, because Bash can do this itself.

See also: [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: I think OP never mentioned what shell is being used.

Comment: Decrementing because doesn't work:# a="${a^^}"
-bash: ${a^^}: bad substitution

Comment: How did you start `bash`, @KevinBuchs? It works here, but it doesn't work with `sh`, for example. Also, what is the content of the variable `a` at that point? For me, this is the most elegant solution, as it avoids forking further processes.

Comment: The `^^` parameter expansion was added in Bash 4.0.

Answer (score 11):

AWK is the right way to convert upper/lower case with full Unicode Support ;-)

```
echo "öäüßè" | awk 'BEGIN { getline; print toupper($0) }'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
a=`echo $a | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`
```

Note the ticks `` ` `` around `echo` and `tr`.

Comment: You made a similar remark above yourself, but here you assume that the shell is `bash` (or sufficiently similar), too. This doesn't work with `fish`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

using a bash script

```
printf "Type your Message Here: " read message

echo Upper Case: $message | tr [:lower:] [:upper:];
echo Lower Case: $message | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is the wrong way to go here, but here's one way it could be done:

```
a=$(awk 'BEGIN { getline; print toupper($0) }')
echo $a
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not get

```
a=`echo $a | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`
```

to work, but

```
a=`echo $a | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
```

did (note additional regex [] brackets.
Within a /usr/bin/sh script this worked as in

```
...
while getopts ":l:c:" option; do  
   case "$option"  
   in  
      l) L_OPT=`echo ${OPTARG}| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`  
         ;;  
      c) C_OPT=`echo ${OPTARG} | tr '[a-z]' [A-Z]'`  
         ;;  
      \?)  
         echo $USAGE  
         exit 1  
         ;;  
   esac  
done  
...
```